# Google Hangouts: Visual alert of new messages when Chrome window is not visible

Tags: macos, google-chrome, notifications, google-hangouts

I use Google Hangouts from within Gmail to text back and forth with people using my Google Voice number. I'm using Chrome on Mac OS X, if that matters.

I don't always have my speakers on and even when I do, I might not be in the room when a new text comes in, so I may miss the audio notification. It would be great if I could get a notification in the Mac menu bar since, for me, it's always visible (I don't ever put apps into true full screen mode). Right now, unless Chrome is in the foreground and my Gmail tab is the active tab, I don't have any visual indication that I have a new text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Google Hangouts Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?hl=en) for Chrome. It supports desktop notifications.

Comment: NOTE: Chrome needs to be able to run in the background for it to work